# How do i set full control permissions for a user on a directory

Tags: c++, winapi

I am running through a sample to allow file access to a SID.  The sample winapi calls are as follows (pseudo):

```
GetNamedSecurityInfo
SetEntriesInAcl //adding on to olddacl
SetNamedSecurityInfo(object, object_type,
        DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pDACL, NULL);
```

- object is a directory under program files.
- object_type is `SE_OBJECT_TYPE::SE_FILE_OBJECT`
- access_perms under the `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` struct is `FILE_ALL_ACCESS`
- access_mode under the `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` struct is `ACCESS_MODE::SET_ACCESS`

Running this code modifies the "special permissions" for my given SID.  It does not, however, modify the more general Full Control/modify/read & execute/list folder contents/etc permissions you see under properties > security tab.

How do I modify those permissions?  Is it a different winapi call, or additional access_perms I need to specify?

Additionally, what is the difference between the special perms I am successfully setting, and the more general permissions that are not changing?

Comment: What did you set for `grfInheritance` ?  IIRC, it has to be `CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE` in order for the GUI to display it as a basic permission.  Note that "special permissions" is a GUI interface concept, not a security concept, and just means "permissions too complicated for me to display accurately in the simplified interface".

Comment: I think CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE is what I ended up doing to get the UI to reflect what I wanted.  Thanks for clarifying that they aren't exactly separate permissions, but a GUI "summary."